# Computing a "concentration of event occurrence" index

Tags: distance

I'm looking at the concentration of an event occurrences in a given interval of time. For example, we suppose that an event occurred 4 times in an interval of length 10. I can represent this as a string where `X` means *the event occurred* whereas `o` means *the event didn't occur*.

The distribution of events could be rather "uniform" in time :

```
X o o X o o X o o X
```

Or it can be "concentrated" like this :

```
X X X o o o o o o X
```

Or like this :

```
X o o o X X o o o X
```

I'm looking for an index or a distance that would allow me to measure and compare the concentration of event occurrence in my interval. Ideally it would allow to compare interval of different lengths, for example it would distinguish between :

```
X o X o X o X o X o X
```

And :

```
X o o o X X o X
```

Do you know of any index or measure that would allow such a thing ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you know what is the minimum & maximum lengths of strings such as `o o o X X o X` you would encounter in your data ?

Comment: @user102890 As it would be weeks in a year, yes, the minimum will be 2 and the maximum 52...

Comment: This question looks similar to http://www.kaggle.com/forums/t/4539/measuring-fragmentation-of-activity

Comment: Is `xxoooo` equally concentrated for you as `xxxxoooooooo`? One might argue that the 2nd is more concentrated because despite that there appeared more positional options to break (`xxxoxooooooo`) the 4 x's cling together still.

Comment: @ttnphns That's a good point. I tend to agree that the second one should be considered more concentrated, but I would deal with a method which would consider both equally.

Comment: @user102890 Thanks for the pointer. It seems that the method described implies that the sequences are all of the same length, but I'll take a look at it.